# f and g are entire and $ \left|f(z)\right| \leq \left|g(z)\right| $ then $\exists \alpha\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=\alpha g(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

If f and g are entire and $\left|f(z)\right| \leq \left|g(z)\right| $ in $\mathbb{C}$ then $\exists \alpha\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=\alpha g(z)$ $ \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\left|\alpha\right| \leq 1$

Is it possible to use without residues and so? I haven't learned neither Laurent series nor residues. This question is from a final exam so I don't know if im supposed to be able to prove it right now or i have to wait to learn those other tools before i can prove it. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: The usual proof uses [Riemann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) on removable singularities.

Comment: Okay, thanks, and do you know where can i find that proof?

Comment: Whoops, didn't found that, it is a duplicate indeed.